# Paracol disrupts proper layout in octavo package

Tags: chapters, paracol, octavo

I'm typesetting a document as a book using the octavo package. All went well until I started to use paracol, which is essential for the layout I seek. Please see the MWE. If you comment out the paracol commands, chapters start on odd / right page, as expected. But this behaviour is lost with paracol, and chapters start either on right or left pages, depending on length of text of preceding chapter. Thanks for helping.

```
\documentclass[foolscap, 12pt]{octavo}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=40pt, headsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{varioref}
%MULTIPLE COLUMNS
\usepackage{paracol}
\twosided[c]
\footnotelayout{m}
\columnsep=0.1\textwidth
\columnratio{0.65}
%Loading polyglossia to use unicode
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{New Peninim MT}

%\newcommand{\parline}{\par\noindent{\centering\makebox[.3\linewidth][s]{* * *}\par}}



%For bibliography

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad3, doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false]{biblatex}

%\bibliography{Midrash.bib}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
{\huge This is a title page}

\chapter{1}
\blindtext[6]

\chapter{2}
\blindtext[2]


 \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: You get the same effect if you use the `book` class, so I suspect it's something to do with `paracol` oir how you have used it.

Comment: Yes, I did try other changes. Just invoking the paracol package disrupts the usual behaviour of having chapters starting on odd pages. Since I have no alternative to paracol, I have to manually force blank pages one by one. Anyone has any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps your best bet is to contact/complain to the `paracol` author. I have tried saving (before the `paracol` package) and restoring the `\cleardoublepage` and `\chapter` macros (after the `paracol` package) but with no effect.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I see no email in the package documentation... Hope the author reads this forum!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with a paracol option:
\twosided[c]

Using the \twosided command without argument restored normal behavior of the book class, and produced same results in the two columns environment.